# Python: Basic modulo - 911 % 11 == 0 returns true

Tags: python, boolean, modulo

I just started learning programming today and ran into an issue. What a way to encourage myself :)

But since it's so basic, maybe someone can explain me quickly what happened here

I have a simple if statement, given to me on a course

```
divisible_by_11 = 11

is_583_divisible_by_11 = None
is_911_divisible_by_11 = None

number_583 = 583

if [number_583 % divisible_by_11 == 0]:  #that line is added by me
    is_583_divisible_by_11 = True
else:
    is_583_divisible_by_11 = False


is_911_divisible_by_11 = None
number_911 = 911

if [number_911 % divisible_by_11 == 0]:  #that line is added by me
    is_911_divisible_by_11 = True
else:
   is_911_divisible_by_11 = False

print(is_583_divisible_by_11)
print(is_911_divisible_by_11)
```

And that returned True twice, which of course it not correct.
To double check it I did

```
print(number_911 / divisible_by_11)
```

And that returned correct result of

```
82.81818181818181
```

In this case, why it happens that " if [number_911 % divisible_by_11 == 0] " returns true even though, in the same program we can check that and that is not correct.

Does it have to do with int/float ? If so how can I force that number to be treated as a float ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be using `[...]` brackets; that creates a *list object*

```
>>> number_583 = 583
>>> divisible_by_11 = 11
>>> [number_583 % divisible_by_11 == 0]
[True]
>>> type([number_583 % divisible_by_11 == 0])
<class 'list'>
```

Because you have a list with at least one element, that's **always going to be true** in a boolean context; see the [*truth value testing* documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing).

This matters when the `==` operation produced a `False` result, like in your `911` test:

```
>>> number_911 = 911
>>> [number_911 % divisible_by_11 == 0]
[False]
>>> bool([number_911 % divisible_by_11 == 0])
True
```

`bool()` returns the same result as what `if` tests for.

Remove those square brackets altogether:

```
if number_583 % divisible_by_11 == 0:
    is_583_divisible_by_11 = True
else:
    is_583_divisible_by_11 = False
```

and

```
if number_911 % divisible_by_11 == 0:
    is_911_divisible_by_11 = True
else:
   is_911_divisible_by_11 = False
```

and you can just assign the result *directly*, since `==` is already going to give you a boolean:

```
is_583_divisible_by_11 = number_583 % divisible_by_11 == 0
is_911_divisible_by_11 = number_911 % divisible_by_11 == 0
```

If you do need to group expressions, you need to use `(...)` round parentheses:

```
is_583_divisible_by_11 = (number_583 % divisible_by_11 == 0)
is_911_divisible_by_11 = (number_911 % divisible_by_11 == 0)
```

but they are redundant here.

Answer (score 1):

Don't put the expression in a list. A non-empty list is always *truthy* even if its contents are all *falsy*. Remove the square brackets:

```
if number_583 % divisible_by_11 == 0:
   ...
```

---

```
>>> bool([False])
True
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because your if statement inadvertently constructs a 1 element list:

```
>>> [number_911 % divisible_by_11 == 0]
[False]
```

A non-empty list is considered `True` for boolean purposes, e.g.

```
if [False]:
    print('True')
else:
    print('False')
```

will print "True".

You can correct your code by simply removing the `[` and `]` to avoid creating a list.

As an aside it is not necessary, or desirable, to initialise your result variables. It's also possible to use no `if` statement at all. This is equivalent:

```
>>> is_583_divisible_by_11 = 583 % 11 == 0
>>> is_583_divisible_by_11
True

>>> is_911_divisible_by_11 = 911 % 11 == 0
>>> is_911_divisible_by_11
False
```

Finally, there is little use in binding literal values to variables with names that simply reiterate the value, such as `number_911`. Just use the number directly.

It makes sense to use constants for things such as `G = 9.8'` (acceleration due to gravity), `PI = 3.14159`, `ROWS = 8`, `COLS = 8` (chess board dimensions).